# Distrobox: export a service

Tags: linux, podman

I've just installed distrobox (version 1.6.0.1 + podman), created a container with Arch Linux and installed some stuff. Now, I would like to export a service.

On my old installation (unfortunatelly, I do not remember the version), I used to do that in the following manner (as recommended by the developers: [distrobox demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eM1p47tow4o); see from ~21:20 to 23:00):

```
distrobox-export --service <service_name>
```

However, apparently the --service flag is gone in the newest version.

How should I export a service in this case?

Thank you in advance for help.